# remove the screen in back of the Tkinter message box

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to show a message box, but without the parent window behind it in Python. This is my code:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog ,tkMessageBox
from fileManagerModule import fileManager
def load():
    global myFile,flag,msg
    flag=True
    options = {}
    options["title"] = "choose a text File"
    options['initialdir'] = '~/'
    fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options)
    myFile = fileManager(fileName)
    myText.delete("1.0", Tkinter.END)
    try:
        line = myFile.readFromFile()
        myText.insert("1.0", line)
    except:
        msg=Tkinter.Tk()
        msg=tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","please choose file to load")
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4iv9.png)

Comment: Please share your entire code :)

Comment: @NehalJWani the code is too big and i don't have details

Comment: Don't show _all_ your code, simply create a complete, working example. You only need to add a few more lines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But first, try searching this site and reading some documentation. This information is available in many places.

Comment: What do you mean by "without the menu behind it"??? Also, your code is too short to reproduce the problem (read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, where's the error message/the main specific problem? And what is this: "[enter image description here][1]
"???

Comment: We need to see more code in the question (not as a screenshot) and a more detailed description of the problem. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ParvizKarimli That was a mal-formatted link to a screenshot, I made an edit to the post.

Comment: I recommend you to read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: done editing check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `withdraw()` function to remove the `window` being displayed in the background to just show the dialog box only.

**try this:**

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog ,tkMessageBox
from fileManagerModule import fileManager
def load():
    global myFile,flag,msg
    flag=True
    options = {}
    options["title"] = "choose a text File"
    options['initialdir'] = '~/'    
    fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options)
    myFile = fileManager(fileName)
    myText.delete("1.0", Tkinter.END)
    try:
        line = myFile.readFromFile()
        myText.insert("1.0", line)
    except:
        msg=Tkinter.Tk()

        msg.withdraw()

        msg=tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","please choose file to load")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code:

```
import Tkinter,tkMessageBox
```

.
.
at program initialisation add a global variable

```
msgWindow = None
```

at your code initialisation add the following lines:
.. before the very first call to tkMessageBox

```
def initialise():
    global msgWindow
    .
    .
    msgWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
    msgWindow.withdraw()
```

in your code where you call tkMessageBox, just call
tkMessageBox the way you normally call it.

```
if not tkMessageBox.askyesno('What to do','Continue ?'):
```

.....

at any exit point where your program terminates, add

```
 msgWindow.destroy()
```

That will do.